# How can you load different scenes (on different clients) on Netcode (MLAPI) in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I'm making a game where the players are not systematically on the same scenes. Unfortunately, it seems not possible to **load different scenes** and **synchronize them**.

I've already researched on the internet for various answers, and the only one that I found was to [build your own scene synchronizer entirely and disable Unity's](https://forum.unity.com/threads/can-you-load-a-specific-scene-for-selected-clients.1321263/). I also already looked at the [docs](https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/netcode/current/basics/scenemanagement/using-networkscenemanager/).

Is there any workaround for this ? Because building a Scene Manager from scratch will be too complex for me and mostly too time-consuming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay,

For everyone encoutering the same problem as me, the only solution I found which was possible to do in my time frame and relatively easy to implement was to use [Mirror](https://mirror-networking.com/). They tackle this problem in [their examples](https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/manual/examples/multiple-additive-scenes).

Have a nice one !

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your project, just try this: have a main scene and **additively load** the (various) "sub" scenes.

- Alternately don't forget your awesome friend **the prefab**. There's no reason a prefab can't be "huge".  Just trivially instantiate the "prefab that's like a scene" as you wish.
- Note that as Riku from Unity says, just turn off scene management in the NetworkManager.
- As the other guy there says, you then have to "do yourself" some management.  You mention that this is a huge task: not at all, it may be trivial.  (Note that if I tell you "I'm making a car racing game": that could be fairly trivial, or incredibly complex. It depends what you're doing.)

Beyond that I do struggle to understand what you're up to.

Is it a mansion with many rooms?  This is commonplace and you do it as one scene.

(I suppose you could say one "BIG" scene, but why, it's only say 10 rooms, that's not especially "big".  You have to know what you're doing with culling, but, you can't engineer multiplayer games (other than just toy hello-world mp games!) unless you're extremely competent with culling.

If you like simply state what you're trying to do!

What are the synced objects .. cars, humans?  If so, in what sense are they "synced" if the players are not even seeing each other? Is it more for just chat/scores or?

One point:

- no matter what Unity are (finally!) up to with mlapi, photon completely blows it away. The new Fusion system is insane technology, and for that matter the Quantum system is also insane. There's a reason they have like a billion users. If you're like working in the business, something to consider, Unity networking is great and you should know it backwards, but you really need to be very expert with Photon to contract around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! The rooms are each one separated in their one scene. I dont wan't to tackle the challenge of doing the synchronization myself because of scope creep and the fact that all of Netcode's code is undocumented and proprietary, not giving any clue to how to do the sync.
The sync is just objects between clients, netcode doesn't seem to allow only certain objects to sync with other objects.

Comment: if all very easy with photon (photonengine.com) ; note too that if this is for a client, tell them "Pro Tip - just use photon" and you will save them a vast amount of money.

Comment: I have around 200+ rooms as unity scenes

Comment: sure, then do this *"Depending on your project, just try this: have a main scene and additively load the (various) "sub" scenes."*

Comment: and also note "As the other guy there says, you then have to "do yourself" some management. You mention that this is a huge task: **not at all, it may be trivial.**"